# how to compile and run two git branches

Tags: git, git-branch

I have two separated branches in git, and one of them is generating the correct output, while the other one which is another way of doing the same procedure is not. I keep jumping between the branches, and modify and then things on one branch and compare it with the stuff on the other branch. Is there way to compile and run them in parallel without moving back and forth between them (using git checkout, etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to clone the repository into another directory, and check out a different branch in each directory.

Comment: I've already done this. But, then I realized that my git push and pull are  mixed with my other cloned version. Possibly because I was using the same id to clone it?

Comment: There's no problem with using the same id to clone it. By creating two clones, and making changes and pushing from both, you're doing effectively the same thing that two different developers would do. You'll have to follow your normal conventions for collaborative work (either rebase or merge, depending on what you prefer).

Comment: Is it possible to completely disconnect a cloned repository from git, to make sure that it doesn't complain about committing changes to the branches every time I want to switch between the branches? In another words, can I change the cloned repo into a local git repository?

Comment: If you haven't made any changes to your source files, you should be able to switch branches without having git complain about anything. There is no way to "disconnect" git and still expect to be able to use git to switch branches.

Comment: So, what if I want to test things locally between the branches without pushing the changes into the repo? I imagine I can use git add, git commit, to switch between the branches. Once I am done, I do git stash and that prevents the locally committed changes to be added to the repo. Right?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "test things locally". If you're tracking down a bug, which it sounds like you are, then create two clones, check out a different branch in each one, then work with the files in the directory (not doing anything with git) until you figure out the problem. Then use git to commit the fix to whichever branch is appropriate.